# Rendering out a table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an application for converting Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa.

The application contains of fields and radiobuttons. The user fills in "start temperature", "end temperate" and "iterator" and chooses to convert from C to F or F to C.

After clicking a button a table is rendered showing the temperature in C and the converted temperature in F (or vice versa). I've tried to do it with a while-loop as well as a for loop, but it doesn't work as it shall.

I know that it is an unnecessary complex solution, and I really should appreciate help with creating a more elegant solution, that works.

```
        var i = 0;

        while (startTemp < endTemp) {
            i += 1;

            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            tRow.CssClass = (i % 2 == 0 ? "white" : "grey");
            tempTable.Rows.Add(tRow);

            startTemp = startTemp + iterator;
            if (startTemp < endTemp) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
                    TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
                    if ((j % 2) == 0) {
                        tCell.Text = startTemp.ToString();
                    }
                    else {
                        if (tempType1 == "°C") {
                            convertedTemp = TemperatureConverter.CelsiusToFahrenheit(startTemp);
                        }
                        else {
                            convertedTemp = TemperatureConverter.FahrenheitToCelsius(startTemp);
                        }
                        tCell.Text = convertedTemp.ToString();
                    }
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
                }
            }
```

Wanted output (iterator = 2):

C--------------------F

```
39          102 
41          105 
43          109 
45          113 
47          116 
49          120
```

EDIT: The solution works fine, except for one thing. If I use 1 as start temp, 10 as end temp and 1 as iterator, it stops at 9 (not at 10 as it should), and I just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is good but I would do only 1 loop

```
TableRow tRow
TableCell tCell
for(int i = startTemp; i < endTemp; i += iterator)
{
tRow = new TableRow();
tRow.CssClass = (i % 2 == 0 ? "white" : "grey");
tempTable.Rows.Add(tRow);

tCell = new TableCell();
tCell.Text = i.ToString();
tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
tCell = new TableCell();

tCell.Text = convert(i);

tRow.Cells.add(tCell);
tempTable.Rows.Add(tRow);

}
```

yours stop at 9 because
at the begining of your while loop you do 9+=1

so i = 10 then if(10 < 10)
so it stops there

So you could do if(startTemp <= endTemp)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're solution is indeed a lot more elegant than mine and it works fine, accept that it needs to change in the same way mine needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it is not bad.  You could alternatively use a class to store the data:

```
public class ConvertData
{
  public decimal Celsius { get; set; }

  public decimal Fahrenheit { get; set; }
}
```

Take a first pass and create the ConvertData objects, storing them in a collection.  Then bind the collection to a Repeater, ListView, etc.